# How to convert base64 to base128 in php

Tags: php, encoding

Can we convert base64 to base128 - and if we can, then how we will do it?

I convert images into base64 using this:

```
$con=file_get_contents('untitled.png');
$en=base64_encode($con);
```

How can I convert this to base128 ?

Comment: Why do you even need Base-128? Is storage so important that you're willing to sacrifice transmission?

Answer (score 1):

You can directly try like

```
require_once 'base128.php';
$en = encode($con);
```

For that you have to include the core file [**this**](https://github.com/seizu/base128/blob/master/base128.php).

Comment: warning, this encoding seems to be bugged and does not always output a valid utf-8 string, see https://github.com/seizu/base128/issues/1